# Whats best practices for handling Drupal 8 core file paths for vendor package.json

Tags: 8, composer

I use drupal-vm when setting up my dev environment and have heard that setting up Drupal core files in the document root is a security issue and should be set in a different way.

So I have set my composer.json to:

```
 "merge-plugin": {
        "include": [
            "docroot/core/composer.json"
        ],
        "recurse": false,
        "replace": false,
        "merge-extra": false
    },
    "installer-paths": {
        "docroot/core": ["type:drupal-core"],
        "docroot/modules/contrib/{$name}": ["type:drupal-module"],
        "docroot/profiles/contrib/{$name}": ["type:drupal-profile"],
        "docroot/themes/contrib/{$name}": ["type:drupal-theme"],
        "docroot/drush/contrib/{$name}": ["type:drupal-drush"],
        "docroot/modules/custom/{$name}": ["type:drupal-custom-module"],
        "docroot/themes/custom/{$name}": ["type:drupal-custom-theme"]
    }
```

I get issues with the autoload not being able to find the vendor/autoload:

```
Warning: require(/var/www/site/docroot/vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/site/docroot/autoload.php on line 14
```

Whats is the best practice for placement of Drupal 8 core files?

Comment: _setting up Drupal core files in the document root is a security issue_ While that's definitely true, it's hard to imagine any way you could move the core folder outside of the web root and still have a working site. It's _designed_ to be in the web root; core modules serve their JS and CSS assets from those folders, for example. So if you move /core outside the webroot, at least the CSS and JS for core modules won't work any more. A common approach is to use https://github.com/drupal-composer/drupal-project to at least move the 3rd party vendor libraries outside the root, but not core

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is a slight misinterpretation of the security risk.

The core/ directory needs to be in your DOCROOT; it has assets that the webserver needs to serve up (JS, CSS, and images).

The vendor/ directory should (mostly) be outside of your DOCROOT; some packages have files that shouldn't really be accessed by the webserver directly and have been the focus of recent SAs.

The exception to this are dependencies that need to be served up or be in the proper place, hence why people use the `installer-paths` to place modules, themes, and JS libraries in the right place.

While not universal, I would say that [drupal-composer/drupal-project](https://github.com/drupal-composer/drupal-project) is a growing best practice, at least for starting points for websites.  This will place vendor/ outside of DOCROOT, take care of the autoloader and scaffold files, and set up a sane set of `installer-paths`.  Even if I am not using this directly, I look to its composer.json for inspiration.